# Почему размеры UIImageView увеличиваются после загрузки в него изображения?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

```
AIPost *post = [postStore objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.dateLabel.text = post.postDate;
    cell.numberLabel.text = post.postNumber;

    if (post.image == nil)
    {
        [post loadImage];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = post.image;
```

После загрузки изображения в UIImageView размеры его становятся равными размерам самого изображения.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался или знает как это исправить?
Ибо я уже пробовал сохранять фрейм UIImageView до загрузки изображения, а уже после загрузки новый фрейм приравнивать к старому.

Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо! С:

Comment: Используете автолайауты или на фреймах?
пробывали поиграться с параметрами `UIViewContentMode`?
попробуйте методы `setContentHuggingPriority:forAxis:` и `setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forAxis:`

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что используется autolayout? Добавьте constaints для width и height. чтобы они не изменялись. Еще можно поиграться с `imageView.contentMode`

Comment: Не использую для этого UIImageView.

Comment: он создан программно?

Comment: @iFreeman нет, на xib'е лежит. Но autolayout отключен.

Comment: во-первых убедитесь, что clipsToBounds = YES, во-вторых, что contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit выставлены у вашего UIImageView (в xib или программно не имеет занчения). По идее в дефалтовых настройках UIImageView все должно быть выставлено верно. Покажите, как именно вы загружаете изображение?